# Codeigniter Form Validation - Is there a way to define multiple different %s when setting error messages?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

Based on the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), %s will be replaced by field name when setting error messages.

> If you include %s in your error string, it will be replaced with the
>   "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.

Is there a way to have multiple %s in the string and define them differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L772) is the line in the form validation library that creates the error message:

```
// Build the error message
$message = sprintf($line, $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']), $param);
```

- `$line`: The error message template, for example "The % field is invalid"
- `$this->_translate_fieldname($row['label'])`: The field's label
- `$param`: The parameter passed the the validation function, if any, `max_length[5]` would pass "5"

So that's the extent of what the form validation class does for you. If you need more flexibility you'll have to [prepare the error message yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198969/398242) <sup><-- might be useful</sup> beforehand with the extra variables already populated.

It might be interesting to extend the form validation class via `core/MY_form_validation.php` and work this functionality in. Unfortunately this line is contained in the main function `_execute` which is very big and messy, and from looking at it now, you'd need to overload some other functions as well. I started to write an example but it actually looks like a chore. You might be better off using:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule_name', 'Your custom message here');
```

More on setting error messages: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors