# CodeIgniter set_message()

Tags: codeigniter, validation

When I am trying to set the custom message for an error under from_validation library in CodeIgniter using the following statement..

```
$this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", "%s already registered. Try a different %s");
```

Instead of getting `Username already registered. Try a different Username` I'm getting `Username already registered. Try a different users.username`

While the documentation says `If you include %s in your error string, it will be replaced with the "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.`

Please get me out of the trap.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem it seems that the language file you are using does not have an index user.username. Define it in the user language file and see what happens.

Here is the Reference to language

[Codeigniter Language Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html)

And

[Codeigntier Language Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem , while i am searching i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13319048/2407522) which mentioned the line in Codeigniter that builds the error message (located in file system/libraries/form_validation.php) near line 673:

```
    // Build the error message
$message = sprintf($line, $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']), $param);
```

I edited it to :

```
// Build the error message
if($rule == 'is_unique') {                                      //my code here

    $vars_num = substr_count($line, '%s');                      //my code here
    for($i = 0; $i < $vars_num; $i++){                          //my code here
        $params[] = $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']); //my code here
    }                                                           //my code here
    $message = vsprintf($line, $params);                        //my code here

} else {                                                        //my code here

    $message = sprintf($line, $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']), $param);

}
```

and it works fine for me .
i know it is not best practice to edit system libraries but maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", "{field} already registered. Try a different {field}");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set Custom Message with Message library of codigniter

For Example 
in Model Coding Like this

```
if(duplicate_user_name ==true){
    $this->messages->add('$user already registered. Try a different $user ', 'error');
}
```

and Print this message with following View

```
$messages = $this->messages->get(); 
            if (is_array($messages)):
                foreach ($messages as $type => $msgs):
                    if (count($msgs > 0)):
                        foreach ($msgs as $message):
                            echo ('<div class="' .  $type .'">' . $message . '</div>');
                       endforeach;
                   endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
```

Comment: This is best answer which i know please see edited answer For more info